# Using physics constant in calculation

Tags: units

I know that mathematica knows physical constants https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Units.html

If I write down = PlanckConstant it "recognizes" hbar.

My question is: how can I use in an efficient way this recognition, because using the "=" I don't know how to affect the variables.

Let's take a concrete example, I want to have numeric evaluation of hbar/kb where hbar is reduced planck constant and kb is boltzmann constant.

But I want hbar and kb used as regular variable of my script, when I do "= ReducedPlanckConstant", it returns me a symbol hbar that I don't know how to affect.

I hope my question is clear ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the `Quantity` command. E.g.

```
Quantity["PlanckConstant"]
```

or for your example:

```
Quantity["ReducedPlanckConstant"]/Quantity["BoltzmanConstant"]
```

To convert to SI units use `UnitConvert`:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckConstant"]/Quantity["BoltzmanConstant"]]
```

gives:

```
Quantity[7.63823*10^-12, "Kelvins" "Seconds"]
```